# How can I can read and modify data from XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exception

Please give me the simplest way to read or modify the XML file data?

Currently I tried this but it throws an exception. My current code is:

```
 XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
 xml.Load("server.xml");

 XmlNodeList serverlist = xml.SelectNodes("//server");
 foreach (XmlNode servernodes in serverlist)
 {
      string server_address = servernodes.SelectSingleNode("addresh").InnerText;
      string server_uname = servernodes.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
      string server_psw = servernodes.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
 }
```

my XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<server>
<address>localhost</address>
<username>myuser</username>
<password>mypassword</password>
</server>
```

and Exception is:

> NullReference Exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What should i do?

Answer : I am correcteed the code in Question. 
         Now it is 100% right.

Comment: you don't have any nodes called "//server" or "address"

Comment: server is my root node

Comment: edit sorry, i misunderstood selectnodes function. Address is still missing though

Comment: so what change i would done in code?

Comment: either spellcheck your xml or change to "addresh"

Comment: there is a typo in your xml for address

Comment: now new Exception is occurs

Comment: no data retrive from XML

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You XML files says `addresh` while you are selecting `address`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class ServerFunction {
    public string LocalHost;
    public string User;
    public string Pass;

    //Copy Constructor
    public ServerFunction(ServerFunction obj)
    {
        LocalHost = obj.LocalHost;
        User = obj.User;
        Pass = obj.Pass;
    }

    //Constructor
    public MemberFunction()
    {
        LocalHost = null;
        User = null;
        Pass = null;
    }

}

//Object of the Class
ServerFunction func = new ServerFunction(); 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("server.xml");

    XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
    {
                func.LocalHost = node.Attributes["address"].Value;
                func.User = node.Attributes["username"].Value;
                func.Pass = node.Attributes["password"].Value;

    }

}
```

Comment: -1: he has elements, not attributes, and your code has the same problem